# Trig substitution for integral with no square root?

Tags: calculus, integration

While studying for an exam I came across a trig substitution integration problem without a square root and I'm not sure how to approach it.

$$\int \frac{1}{1+3x^2} \, dx $$

Any ideas?

Comment: the first thing i got to my mind is use $x = tan(\theta)$ and $1 = 3-2$

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a straightforward $\arctan$ integral.
Try writing it in the form
$$
\int \frac{f'(x) } {1+[f(x)]^2} \mathrm{d} x.
$$

It should be clear to you, comparing the denominators, that $f(x)=\sqrt{3}x$.